# Get-AdGroupMember for multiple groups

Tags: powershell-5.0

How do I check if the mentioned security groups exists or not? I would also want the exported .csv to mention 'No members' instead of skipping it.

Also, how do I refine below script? And I would like to get member's details.

```
$group_list = get-content C:\temp\group_list.txt

$results = foreach($group in $group_list){

$checkgroup = get-adgroup -filter {name -eq $group} | select name

if($checkgroup -ne $null){
                    
    $members = get-adgroupmember $group | select samaccountname
    
    if($members -ne $null){
    [PSCustomObject]@{GroupName=$group;Members=($members.samaccountname | Out-String).Trim()}
    }
    else{
    [PSCustomObject]@{GroupName=$group;Members="None"}
    }    
}
else{
    [PSCustomObject]@{GroupName=$group;Members="Group not exist"}
}
}

$results | Export-csv C:\temp\Group_Members.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Limit your post to a single question please.

Answer (score 0):

```
# output active directory groups and members to csv (also output empty groups with 'No Members' value)
# assumes run on domain controller or import of ActiveDirectory module

$allgroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter *

$result = foreach ( $group in $allgroups ) {

    $hash = @{GroupName=$group.SamAccountName;Member=''}
    $groupid = $group.distinguishedname
    
    if ( $members = Get-ADGroupMember $groupid ) {
            
            foreach ( $member in $members ) {

                $hash.Member = $member.Name
                New-Object psObject -Property $hash
            }
    }
    else {
        $displayname = "No Members"
        $hash.Member = $displayname
        New-Object psObject -Property $hash
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\ADGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation

# End
```

Comment: This works but not as intended. I have a list of ad groups. I want to check if the groups exist or not. If it does, it should show group members and their details. I was trying to enclose in try-catch or if-else but not successful yet

Comment: you should put all the details of your requiremnts in your initial question. you didn't clearly state that you wanted to import a list or that you need details of the members. And you haven't said which details you need.  And you've added your code to the question since I answered it.  And you haven't said where you are having trouble in the script?

Comment: The script does not have issue but I would like to get more user details like using get-aduser. I keep getting error. Also, I tried using hash like you instead of pscustomobject but my exported csv have empty cells.

Comment: What error are you getting?  For details you would add Get-ADUser into this part: foreach ( $member in $members ) {

                $hash.Member = $member.Name
                New-Object psObject -Property $hash
            }